# Spark RDD: lookup from other RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to perform the quickest lookup possible in Spark, as part of some practice rolling-my-own association rules module. Please note that I know the metric below, confidence, is supported in PySpark. This is just an example -- another metric, lift, is not supported, yet I intend to use the results from this discussion to develop that.

As part of calculating the confidence of a rule, I need to look at how often the antecedent and consequent occur together, as well as how often the antecedent occurs across the whole transaction set (in this case, `rdd`).

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable, no_empty=True):
    ''' Produce the powerset for a given iterable '''
    s = list(iterable)
    combos = (combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
    powerset = chain.from_iterable(combos)
    return (el for el in powerset if el) if no_empty else powerset

# Set-up transaction set
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [
        ('a',),
        ('a', 'b'),
        ('a', 'b'),
        ('b', 'c'),
        ('a', 'c'),
        ('a', 'b'),
        ('b', 'c'),
        ('c',),
        ('b'),
    ]
)

# Create an RDD with the counts of each
# possible itemset
counts = (
    rdd
    .flatMap(lambda x: powerset(x))
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
    .map(lambda x: (frozenset(x[0]), x[1]))
)

# Function to calculate confidence of a rule
confidence = lambda x: counts.lookup(frozenset(x)) / counts.lookup((frozenset(x[1]),))

confidence_result = (
    rdd
    # Must be applied to length-two and greater itemsets
    .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
    .map(confidence)
)
```

For those familiar with this type of lookup problem, you'll know that this type of Exception is raised:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

One way to get around this exception is to convert `counts` to a dictionary:

```
counts = dict(counts.collect())

confidence = lambda x: (x, counts[frozenset(x)] / counts[frozenset(x[1])])

confidence_result = (
    rdd
    # Must be applied to length-two and greater itemsets
    .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
    .map(confidence)
)
```

Which gives me my result. But the process of running `counts.collect` is very expensive, since in reality I have a dataset with 50m+ records. Is there a better option for performing this type of lookup?

Answer (score 1):

If your target metric can be independently calculated on each RDD partition and then combined to achieve the target result, you can use `mapPartitions` instead of `map` when calculating your metric.

The generic flow should be something like:

```
metric_result = (
    rdd
    # apply your metric calculation independently on each partition       
    .mapPartitions(confidence_partial) 
    # collect results from the partitions into a single list of results
    .collect()
    # reduce the list to combine the metrics calculated on each partition
    .reduce(confidence_combine)
)
```

Both `confidence_partial` and `confidence_combine` are regular python function that take an iterator/list input.

As an aside, you would probably get a huge performance boost by using dataframe API and native expression functions to calculate your metric.

Comment: I don't think that solves the issue. The issue is with having to create an external lookup. The computation itself is easy - I just can't find a way to quickly develop a lookup table like a dictionary for use in the function.

Comment: Spark RDD represent a distributed dataset, you can't have a unique central lookup function with these structures. The way to do it is to split your function in two parts as described: one can be an local lookup in each partition and then you collect the results and combine them for your final result.